# Assistance needed in VBA to extract unique values based on one condition

Tags: vba

I have a working code that extract the distinct values from a sheet, however it only gives me the total of distinct values.
I need it to be working with a certain condition, at the moment i have 13 different conditions, and each condition should get that specific value filled in to a specific cell on an other sheet.

example
condition 1: 46130288, the result of the distinct values should be filled into Sheet KPI cell D3
condition 2: 55202136, the result of the distinct values should be filled into Sheet KPI cell D6.

The Working code for a total of distinct values looks like this:

```
Sub CntOrder()
    Dim Uni As Collection, cl As Range, LpRange As Range
    Dim clswfrm As Range, clswcst As Range, myRng As Range
    Dim TotUni As Long
    '*************
    Set myRng = Sheets("957").[E:E]    'define your sheet/range
    '*************
    On Error Resume Next
    Set clswfrm = myRng.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
    Set clswcst = myRng.SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    Set myRng = Nothing    'free up memory
    On Error GoTo 0
    If clswfrm Is Nothing And clswcst Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Unique Cells"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not clswfrm Is Nothing And Not clswcst Is Nothing Then
        Set LpRange = Union(clswcst, clswfrm)
    ElseIf clswfrm Is Nothing Then Set LpRange = clswcst
    Else: Set LpRange = clswfrm
    End If
    Set clswfrm = Nothing: Set clswcst = Nothing    'Free up memory
    Set Uni = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cl In LpRange
        Uni.Add cl.Value - 2, CStr(cl.Value)    'assign unique key string
    Next cl
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set LpRange = Nothing    'free up memory
    TotUni = Uni.Count
    Set Uni = Nothing    ''free up memory
    Range("D2") = TotUni    'Work with the Unique value total here (replace msgbox)
End Sub
```

Hope someone could help me in getting the code above to check Sheet("957").Range("T:T") after the conditions to be met

Comment: If you want unique values and counts then a Dictionary is more useful, but it's not clear to me what you mean by "I need it to be working with a certain condition".  Also indenting is a thing. please.

Comment: Hello Tim, i have 13 different customer numbers, but the sheet im trying to extract the values from has all the customer numbers in it, and i need somehow to read how many unique values each customer number have on this sheet.

Comment: You should watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=42).  You don't have to set your ranges to nothing.  You aren't going to get any noticeable performance increase by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will get you started.

```
Sub CntOrder()
    Dim Uni As Object
    Dim r As Range, Target As Range

    With Sheets("957")
        Set Target = Intersect(.Columns("E"), .UsedRange)    'Set the Target range to the used portion of column E
    End With

    If Target Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Unique Cells"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set Uni = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each r In Target    'assign unique key & count occurence
        Uni(r.Value) = Uni(r.Value) + 1    'The key is a variant type
    Next

    With Sheets("Sheet KPI")
        .Range("D2") = Uni.Count
        .Range("D3").Resize(Uni.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(Uni.Keys) 'Assign the unique value
        .Range("E3").Resize(Uni.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(Uni.Items) ' Assign the counts of each unique vaule
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, think ill have to read up on this during the weekend :). The result im after is if the target found in Sheet("957").Range("T:T").Value = 46130288 then the count should be on column E and only this result should then be shown in the Sheet("KPI").Range("D2")      ill see if i can get my head around it, thanks

Comment: You should probably post a download link for the file or some screenshots of your data and possible a screenshot of the desired result.  You should watch the video that I linked in a previous comment.